# What's the difference between PLA and PAL logic devices? Is there one?

Tags: digital-logic, programmable-logic

I've seen both PAL (which I understand is Programmable Array Logic) and PLA (I don't know what this one stands for. Programmable Logic Array?) used to refer to certain types of programmable logic devices that came before modern PLDs, CPLDs, and FPGAs. Is there a semantic difference between the terms, or are they two words for the same class of device?

I was originally going to ask about GALs as well, but I found a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38120/what-is-the-difference-between-a-gal-and-a-pal) on here that already answers that part.

Comment: please do research before you post your question ..... if you do not understand the results of your research, then ask a question

Comment: @jsotola I did some research and couldn't find anything conclusive. Maybe I wasn't using the right search terms?

Comment: search for `pal pla`

Comment: @jsotola Hmm. I probably should have thought to do that. I did research looking for info on PALs, PLAs, _and_ GALs, and nothing I found seemed to differentiate between PLAs and PALs. I removed the GAL from this question when I found the linked question, but I didn't think to try to look for information on PLA vs PAL without mentioning GAL.

Comment: no problem  .... i always search for the minimal number of words unless i'm searching for the cause of some error code, then i use the actual error code text in its entirety

Comment: @jsotola Well, in case anyone else needs it, I might write up an answer to my own question here when I have a chance to. Thanks for the assistance, even if it did make me feel dumb.

Comment: I'm not sufficiently confident to write an answer, but I think PLA was a generic term while PAL and GAL were trademarks.

Comment: @Hearth This link [providing a brief history](https://www.computerhistory.org/siliconengine/pal-user-programmable-logic-devices-introduced/) is close to my own memory. It might give you some additional companies and developer names to search, as well.

Comment: PALs and GALs were typically 20 and 16 pin packages with limited inputs and outputs.  PLAs are larger devices, more logic, more pins.